# Change the size of the label in an IPython notebook widget

Tags: widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook

This is really a trivial problem, but it is still annoying. I'm writing a tool to allow a user to set a bunch of numerical parameters for an analysis in the IPython notebook. I've set it up as a bunch of `FloatTextWidget`s in a `ContainerWidget`. They have rather long labels like "Number of Posture Points" or "Background Disk Radius". They don't line up nicely. This is because of the length: as explained on [this page](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jvns/ipython/blob/master/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Widget%20Alignment.ipynb), "The label of the widget has a fixed minimum width. The text of the label is always right aligned and the widget is left aligned... If a label is longer than the minimum width, the widget is shifted to the right."

My labels exceed the "fixed minimum width". What I want to know is how to change it. I have poked around in the Widget source code, and I can't find this anywhere.

**EDIT:** In response to @Jakob, [here is some code](http://pastebin.com/c9wxUz25), and here is a screenshot [image: here is a screenshot]

In this example, "Threshold:" is small enough to fit within the label width, but all the others are too long.

Comment: Can you provide some code, to play with, please?

Comment: @Jakob: I added a link to some code, and a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the narrow answer to my question: the minimum field width is defined in `site-packages/IPython/html/static/style/ipython.min.css` (located wherever your python libraries live -- on my Max that is `/Library/Python/2.7/`), where `widget-hlabel` is defined by

```
.widget-hlabel{min-width:10ex;padding-right:8px;padding-top:3px;text-align:right;vertical-align:text-top}
```

`min-width:10ex` is the relevant part.

Although one can override this for an entire document, I don't see an easy way to change it one widget at a time. It would have to be done on the JavaScript side, since the `FloatTextWidget` class doesn't give separate access to the label component of the Widget from the python side. That would require developing a custom widget subclassed from `FloatTextWidget`, which seems like way too much effort for such a simple problem, and fragile to boot. At least, that's the only way I see to do it -- corrections welcome.

Instead, I have decided to eschew altogether the automatic labeling of widgets with their descriptions, and instead construct each label as an `HTMLWidget`, which gives me complete control over its appearance. Here's what that looks like: [image: screenshot]

Comment: I agree to your findings, that there is no easy way to change the style of individual widgets. However, looking at your new image, I wonder why you not simply inject some css style into the page to change the `min-width` of the widget-hlabel class? This results in a very similar view than yours.

Comment: I don't want to change the min-width of ALL the labels in the page, only the ones in this particular panel of the tool. (This will be one tab of a `TabWidget`, eventually.) If you can tell me how to inject CSS so that it will only apply locally, that would be great.

Answer (score 8):

To change the style from within the notebook:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

display(HTML('''<style>
    .widget-label { min-width: 20ex !important; }
</style>'''))
```

Comment: Here's [another procedure](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2364#issuecomment-482375019).

Answer (score 4):

use the layout argument for each widget. Here's the link to the documentation: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html
In particular it says, you an define description and widget separately in an HBox like this:

```
    from ipywidgets import HBox, Label, Layout
    label_layout = Layout(width='100px',height='30px')
    HBox([Label('A description',layout=label_layout), IntSlider()])
```